# The solution to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}$ in a form not considered closed form?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Is there a solution to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}$ that isn't in the standard closed form?  I was wondering if a looser definition of "solution" could allow someone to solve this or if the solution already exists.

Obviously $\zeta(3)$ doesn't cut it, it must be a solution that I can use to calculate the series without using a series directly equal to the one I'm trying to solve.

Or close bounds that allow squeeze theorem to be applied, as some methods use to solve $\zeta(2)$?  Close bounds findable through calculus based methods?

Comment: Pretty sure nothing like that is known for any $\zeta(2n+1),n>0$.

Comment: your sum is $\zeta(3)$

Comment: There are other representations of $\zeta(s)$ that permit fast and efficient numerical approximations.

Comment: What do you mean by a solution?

Comment: @zhw. I don't want numerical based methods.  But if it is reduceable to something like the Lambert W function, something usually calculated by numerical methods, but sort of a special function, I'd accept that.

Comment: Choose the tag Riemann-zeta with mathoverflow, you will find useful informations.

Comment: Given your comment "if it is reduceable to something like the Lambert W function, something usually calculated by numerical methods, but sort of a special function, I'd accept that," does the result $$\zeta(3)=\frac43 \eta(3)$$suffice.  The eta function has an alternating series representation and thus, not only rapidly converges for $s=3$, but provides a built-in error bound.  I've posted a solution using this way forward.   -Mark

Comment: This is [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant). The linked page contains some alternative forms but none would really be considered to be "closed form". I guess the best we can say about it is that it is irrational.

Comment: I don't understand the question at 100%, because my english is bad. But I say you that a nice reference is *Around Apéry's constant*, by Walther Janous (that is provided by http://www.emis.de). After I say you some words from the viewpoint of an amateur: if I try to get $\zeta(3)\zeta(2)$ from the **Dirichlet series for the sum of divisor function**, since I don't know to sum the series in RHS, then I can not conclude nothing. Neither if I take **Cauchy products** like $(\zeta(3))^2$ or different like $\zeta(3)\cdot\text{infinite series}$ since I don't know how get the sum of convolutions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps, but there are other representations of the Riemann-Zeta Function that permit faster convergence rates than the representation afforded by the series

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$

One such representation is provided in terms of the alternating series representation of the [Dirichlet Eta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

$$\begin{align}
\zeta(s)&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\right)\eta(s)}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

For $s=3$, we see from $(1)$ that $\zeta(3)$ can be expressed as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\zeta(3)=\frac43 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}} \tag 2$$

Note that $(3)$ provides a rapidly converging series with a built-in error bound on the partial sums provided by the absolute value of the next term of the series.  Thus, we can immediately find the number of terms in the series required to yield an approximation within a specified error.

For example, if we want an approximation with error less than $10^{-5}$, then we can choose the number of terms $N-1$ such that $N>\left(\frac43 10^5\right)^{1/3}\approx 51.087$.  Therefore, by summing the first $51$ terms of the series in $(2)$ we are guaranteed that the result will have an error less than $10^{-5}$.

Similarly, if we want an approximation with an error less than $10^{-6}$, then we can choose the number of terms $N-1$ such that $N> \left(\frac43 10^5\right)^{1/3}\approx 110.064$.  Therefore, by summing the first $110$ terms of the series in $(2)$ we are guaranteed that the result will have an error less than $10^{-6}$.

> Other alternating series representations given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant#Fast_convergence) provide even faster convergence rates than $(2)$.

Comment: Just a thought, the following series converges much faster: $$\zeta(3)=\frac43\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^3}$$

Comment: @simplybeautifulart  At the end of the answer, you'll find a link to a reference that provides representations that converge very rapidly.